# How can I write a multiplication table with all the elements in the array in recursive programming?

Tags: python, arrays, recursion

I am creating a multiplication table with all the elements in the array such as multiply all the elements(2,3,7,8,10) with first element(2). Then, multiply the new values(4,6,14,16,20) with second element(3) and so on.

I could achieve the result relatively simply with a loop.

```
def multiplication(arr):
    newArr = arr.copy()
    for j in range(len(arr)):
        newArr= [val*arr[j] for val in newArr]
    return newArr

print(multiplication([2,3,7,8,10]))
```

But when I try to solve it recursively, I am not able to retain the original elements with multiplied values.

```
def multiplicationRecursively(arr, index=0):
    if (index >= len(arr)):
        return arr
    arr = [val*arr[index] for val in arr]
    return multiplicationRecursively(arr, index+1)

print(multiplicationRecursively([2,3,7,8,10]))
```

Am I doing something wrong? I think I need to figure out how to retain the original array to get correct multiplier ? I'm learning the Recursive Programming so I'm not willing to use the probably built-in methods.

Comment: You can recurs over index and a multiplier similar to how you have done using for loop. start with multiplier set to the first element of the array and then keep multiplying it with next element of the array until the end. see my answer below

Comment: I admit I'd have never figured out that way, really neat solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resulting array is nothing but the multiplication of all elements of the original array with each element of the original array. So we can write a recursion as following :

```
def multiplicationRecursively(arr, mulitplier, index=1):

if (index <= len(arr) -1):
    mulitplier = mulitplier * arr[index]
    return multiplicationRecursively(arr, mulitplier, index+1)
return [mulitplier*val for val in arr]

print(multiplicationRecursively([2,3,7,8,10], 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a whack answer but I believe the issue is the fact that you are no longer multiplying each value with its original value.

```py
def multiplicationRecursively(arr: list, original = None, i = 0):

    if not original:
        return multiplicationRecursively(arr, arr.copy())

    #  Here is the base case
    if (i == len(arr)):
        return arr

    newArr = [v * original[i] for v in arr]
    
    return multiplicationRecursively(newArr, original, i + 1)


print( multiplicationRecursively( [2, 3, 7, 8, 10] ))
```

With this method, you will retain your original multiplyers and you'll end up with the same results.

*This obviously isn't the best way of writing this as a recursion.*

Answer (score 0):

i fully understand the problem you are facing , use this code and you will get the expected result.

```
 def multiplication_table(array, index = 0):

    multiplier = array.copy()
    
    if (index >= len(array)): 

     return ("")

    else:
        multipling_number = multiplier[index]
        table =[multipling_number*i for i in array]
        print (table, end='\n')

        return multiplication_table(array, index+1)

     Test: 
     array=[1,2,3,4,5]

     print(multiplication_table(array))
     output:
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
     [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
     [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
     [4, 8, 12, 16, 20]
     [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
```